How do I set my hour and minute from a variable inside TZDateTime?:Flutter
I schedule user notifications. It works well, but I want to add the hour and minute that come from the user only I have two variables, the hour and the minute, but I do not know where to put the variables. I tried to put them with the year, month, and day, but to no avail. Can I achieve that?
Example:
    var  schduelTime =  tz.TZDateTime(
          tz.local,
          currentzone.year,
          currentzone.month,
          currentzone.day,
          My_hour,
          My_minute,

        );

//Code
import 'package:adhdhkar_muslim/virb_uli.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:adhdhkar_muslim/virb_uli.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:flutter_timezone/flutter_timezone.dart';
import 'virb_uli.dart';
class NotificationService {
  static FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

   static Future init()async{
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    InitializationSettings settings = const InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
      iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
    );

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      settings,
      
     // onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:(details) {},
      //onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:(details){},
    );

   }

static void showBasicNotification() async {
  const AndroidNotificationDetails android = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'id 3',
    "schdulrd Notf",
    importance: Importance.max,
    priority: Priority.high,

  );
  NotificationDetails details = const NotificationDetails(
    android: android,
  );
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
 
 var  currentzone = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
 
 var  schduelTime =  tz.TZDateTime(
          tz.local,
          currentzone.year,
          currentzone.month,
          currentzone.day,
          19,
          30,

        );
if (schduelTime.isBefore(currentzone)) {

 schduelTime = schduelTime.add(const Duration(days: 1));
   //schduelTime = schduelTime.add(const Duration(hours: 1));
   
 }
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
   1,
  "اذكار الصباح ",
  "الله اكبر",
  schduelTime
   ,
  details,
   uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);

}

}

I don't want to add the time manually like in the code. I don't want that

Is there a way?

Maybe you can use the 'add' method as shown in
schduelTime = schduelTime.add(const Duration(days: 1));

But you can replace the duration with a simple equation that subtracts the date and time that the user enters from the DateTime.now().
Like now the time is 05:30 am and wanna it 02:30 pm so subtract it and the result will be 3 hours.
So you added this 3 hours with 'add' method.

How do I do that? Can you add something to the code to clarify the idea?

The time entered by the user is of type TimeOfDay

TimeOfDay timeOfDaydk = const TimeOfDay(hour:5, minute:30); like this

Is it like this?           schduelTime = schduelTime.add( Duration(hours:5-3));

This code works when the current date is added.
       var dateTime = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day, 23, 7, 0);
   var  schduelTime =  tz.TZDateTime.from(dateTime, tz.local);
 

But it gives this error:
Exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument (scheduledDate): Must be a date in the future: Instance of 'TZDateTime')
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
 class NotificationService {
      static FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
          FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    
       static Future init()async{
        // ignore: unused_local_variable
        InitializationSettings settings = const InitializationSettings(
          android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
          iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
        );
    
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
          settings,
          
         // onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:(details) {},
          //onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:(details){},
        );
    
       }
    
    static void showBasicNotification() async {
      const AndroidNotificationDetails android = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'id 3',
        "schdulrd Notf",
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
    
      );
      NotificationDetails details = const NotificationDetails(
        android: android,
      );
      tz.initializeTimeZones();
     
     //var  currentzone = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
      var dateTime = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day, 23, 7, 0);
       var  schduelTime =  tz.TZDateTime.from(dateTime, tz.local);
        tz.initializeTimeZones();
        if (schduelTime.isBefore(dateTime)) {
        
         schduelTime = schduelTime.add(const Duration(days: 1));
           //schduelTime = schduelTime.add(const Duration(hours: 1));
           
         }
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
       5,
      'Yess',
      'hahahahahah',
       schduelTime,
      details,
       uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
    
    }
    
    }


I posted an answer that it works, but there is one problem. How to solve it?
Exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument (scheduledDate): Must be a date in the future: Instance of 'TZDateTime')
